# Webpack + ExtractTextPlugin not generating CSS

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack

I've gone through about every stackoverflow post about this, but none of the solutions are working for me. I am trying to separate out my styles from  bundle.js to a separate css file. Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
    app: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    style: path.join(__dirname, 'builds', 'main.css'),
    build: path.join(__dirname, 'builds')
};

let plugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name:      'main', // Move dependencies to our main file
        children:  true, // Look for common dependencies in all children,
        minChunks: 2, // How many times a dependency must come up before being extracted
    }),

    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
];

if (production) {
    plugins = plugins.concat([
        //new ExtractTextPlugin('./builds/app.css'),
        // Cleanup the builds/ folder before
        // compiling our final assets
        new CleanPlugin('builds'),

        // This plugin looks for similar chunks and files
        // and merges them for better caching by the user
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

        // This plugins optimizes chunks and modules by
        // how much they are used in your app
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),

        // This plugin prevents Webpack from creating chunks
        // that would be too small to be worth loading separately
        new webpack.optimize.MinChunkSizePlugin({
            minChunkSize: 51200, // ~50kb
        }),

        // This plugin minifies all the Javascript code of the final bundle
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            mangle:   true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false, // Suppress uglification warnings
            },
        }),

        // This plugins defines various variables that we can set to false
        // in production to avoid code related to them from being compiled
        // in our final bundle
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __SERVER__:      !production,
            __DEVELOPMENT__: !production,
            __DEVTOOLS__:    !production,
            'process.env':   {
                BABEL_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
            },
        }),



    ]);
}

module.exports = {
    debug: !production,
    devtool: production ? false : 'eval',
    entry: './src',
    output: {
        path:          'builds',
        filename:      production ? '[name]-[hash].js' : 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
        publicPath:    'builds/',
    },
    // need this so code updates are detected across the time space continuum
    // (i.e. from local dev IDE to Vagrant)
    watchOptions : {
        poll: 300
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                loader: 'eslint',
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                // Skip any files outside of your project's `src` directory
                include: [
                    PATHS.app
                ],
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
                // Only run `.js` and `.jsx` files through Babel
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                // Options to configure babel with
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader','css!sass')
            },
            // {
            //  test: /\.scss$/,
            //  exclude: '/node_modules/',
            //  loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'],
            // },
            {
                test: /\.html/,
                loader: 'html',
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

Here is the structure of my files:

```
/builds
   bundle.js
/src
   Button.html
   Button.js
   Button.scss
   .
   .
   .
```

Here is what one of my component's js files looks like:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import template from './Button.html';
import Mustache from 'mustache';
require('./Button.scss');

export default class Button {
    constructor(link) {
        this.link = link;
    }


    onClick(event) {
        console.log('event!');
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render(node) {
        const text = $(node).text();

        // Render our button
        $(node).html(
            Mustache.render(template, {text})
        );

        // Attach our
        $('.button').click(this.onClick.bind(this));
    }


}
```

I have also tried doing `import './Button.scss'`, but that didn't work either. The reason I have my file setup like this is to make my components modular (vs. putting all the scss files, js files, and html into separate folders, respectively).

With this setup, this is the output of webpack:

```
Hash: 6a3f7c601a79a3c623ac
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 9413ms
                         Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                     bundle.js   338 kB       0  [emitted]  main
button-b1a788bd9f86b45a8e59.js  4.39 kB       1  [emitted]  button
     2-6833a661a664e93b75c4.js  4.04 kB       2  [emitted]
     3-c1f2bacfb61ab3b0db4e.js  94.2 kB       3  [emitted]
   [0] ./src/index.js 538 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] ./src/Components/Button.js 1.81 kB {1} [built] [1 warning]
   [2] ./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js 267 kB {0} [built]
   [3] ./src/Components/Button.html 72 bytes {1} [built]
   [4] ./~/mustache/mustache.js 19.4 kB {0} [built]
   [5] ./src/Components/Button.scss 1.05 kB {1} [built]
   [6] ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/Components/Button.scss 300 bytes {1} [built]
   [7] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
   [8] ./~/style-loader/addStyles.js 7.15 kB {0} [built]
   [9] ./src/Components/Header.js 1.56 kB {2} [built]
  [10] ./src/Components/Header.html 64 bytes {2} [built]
  [11] ./src/Components/Header.scss 1.05 kB {2} [built]
  [12] ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/Components/Header.scss 192 bytes {2} [built]
  [13] ./src/Components/Foundation.js 37 bytes {3} [built]
  [14] ./src/Components/app.scss 1.04 kB {3} [built]
  [15] ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/Components/app.scss 88.7 kB {3} [built]
```

I have never seen a css file built while trying to use ExtractTextPlugin. I'm almost certain I'm missing one stupid little thing, but I just don't know what it is.

Comment: I'm seeing that you declare `plugins`, did you add it into the config?

Comment: Yes, I have added the plugins into my config.

Comment: Can you add the full config?

Comment: I just edited my question to include the entire config.

Comment: I suggest you do a console.log(config) and verify it looks correct.

Comment: I was able to get farther. I hadn't added `require('app.scss')` into my index.js. I can now generate style.css.

However, I still have the issue of including other sass files that are not imported via app.scss. Is there a way to maintain my modular structure that I specified in the original question?